# Что означает эта строчка в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Непонятна эта строчка `divs = divs + [d, n//d]`

```
from math import sqrt

divCount = 2

for n in range(174457, 174505 + 1):
    divs = []
    q = round(sqrt(n))
    for d in range(2, q):
        if n % d == 0:
            divs = divs + [d, n // d]
            if len(divs) > divCount: break
    if len(divs) > divCount:
        print(*divs)
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/qsquLek.png

Comment: Текстовую информацию (код) нужно добавлять в вопрос в текстовом виде, а не в виде картинок.

Answer (score 5):

К массиву `divs` добавляется два значения, `d`, `n // d`

к примеру

```
lst = [0, 1]
lst = lst + [2, 3]

print(lst)
```

> ```
> [0, 1, 2, 3]
> ```

это также можно записать так:

```
divs.append(d)
divs.append(n // d)
```

и так:

```
divs.extend([d, n // d])
```